# Issue with CSS showing images in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a blog and changed some of the php and css of the template so it could show the exact image size that I need, as you can see below:

http://hynx.com.br/?page_id=230

The old template used to show 4 images per line, and it seems to be forcing that, even after the resize. I've tried to change almost everywhere with firebug to make that huge gap before the "Goof Troop" image go away, but I just can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop probably has a line like this at the end.

```
<?php if($i%4==0) : ?><?php endif; ?>
```

If so just change it to 3.

Comment: Hi, I didn't change anything, just theme options. Check now how it behaves with only 6 posts per page. It's too strange...

Comment: Did you open up your index.php and look at the loop to see if that line was at the end of it?

Comment: Just solved the issue.

In the PHP the thumbnail was being set only with a width parameter, when I inserted an image with a larger height it broke the layout.

I've fixed by putting a limit on the height value.

Thanks.